# Linux kernel module hangs during unloading

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I'm trying to make programming project from first chapter of book 'Operating System Concepts'. The task is to write Linux kernel module, which iterates structures using kernel list data structure. I've written following code:

```c
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/list.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>

struct birthday {
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
    struct list_head list;  
};

struct list_head birthday_list;

struct birthday *createBirthday(int day, int month, int year)
{
    struct birthday *person = kmalloc(sizeof(struct birthday), GFP_KERNEL);

    person->day = day;
    person->month = month;
    person->year = year;

    return person;
}

void printInfo(char *str)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "OS Module: %s", str);
}

int simple_init(void)
{
    struct birthday *person = createBirthday(13, 4, 1987);
    struct birthday *ptr;

    printInfo("Loading Module\n");

    LIST_HEAD(birthday_list);

    list_add_tail(&person->list, &birthday_list);
    person = createBirthday(14, 4, 1987);
    list_add_tail(&person->list, &birthday_list);
    person = createBirthday(15, 4, 1987);
    list_add_tail(&person->list, &birthday_list);
    person = createBirthday(16, 4, 1987);
    list_add_tail(&person->list, &birthday_list);
    person = createBirthday(17, 4, 1987);
    list_add_tail(&person->list, &birthday_list);

    list_for_each_entry(ptr, &birthday_list, list) {
        printk(KERN_INFO "OS Module: Day %d.%d.%d\n", ptr->day, ptr->month, ptr->year);
    }

       return 0;
}

void simple_exit(void)
{
    struct birthday *tmp;
    struct list_head *ptr, *next;

    printInfo("Removing Module\n");

    if (list_empty(&birthday_list)) {
        printInfo("List is empty");
        return;
    }

    list_for_each_safe(ptr, next, &birthday_list){
        tmp = list_entry(ptr, struct birthday, list);
        printk(KERN_INFO "OS Module: Removing %d.%d.%d\n", tmp->day, tmp->month, tmp->year);
        list_del(ptr);
        kfree(tmp);
    }

    //list_for_each_entry_safe(ptr, next, &birthday_list, list) {
    //  printk(KERN_INFO "OS Module: Removing %d.%d.%d\n", ptr->day, ptr->month, ptr->year);
    //  list_del(&ptr->list);
    //  kfree(ptr);
    //}

    printInfo("Module removed\n");
}

module_init( simple_init );
module_exit( simple_exit );

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Simple Module");
MODULE_AUTHOR("MP");
```

After installing and deleting module I haven't seen messages about removing module.

```
~/kernelModule $ sudo insmod simple.ko
~/kernelModule $ sudo rmmod -f simple
~/kernelModule $ dmesg | grep 'OS Module'
[  386.590198] OS Module: Loading Module
[  386.590201] OS Module: Day 13.4.1987
[  386.590202] OS Module: Day 14.1.1964
[  386.590203] OS Module: Day 2.6.1964
[  386.590204] OS Module: Day 13.8.1986
[  386.590204] OS Module: Day 10.6.1990
[  396.647828] OS Module: Removing Module
~/kernelModule $ sudo rmmod -f simple
rmmod: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:769 kmod_module_remove_module() could not remove 'simple': Device or resource busy
rmmod: ERROR: could not remove module simple: Device or resource busy
```

As I understand, my module hangs during removing. And I cannot understand why. Both releasing codes (commented too) make module hang.

Comment: Have you tried to add some more `printk` traces to figure out the exact line of code where code hangs?

Comment: in `simple_init` function you need to use `LIST_HEAD_INIT` instead of `LIST_HEAD`: the latter *declares and initializes local* variable instead of initializing global one.

Comment: can use INIT_LIST_HEAD(&birthday_list) or LIST_HEAD_INIT.

Comment: @Tsyvarev. @, @GauthamKantharaju Thanks, `INIT_LIST_HEAD` helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `INIT_LIST_HEAD(&birthday_list)` instead of `LIST_HEAD(birthday_list)` helps to solve the poblem.